# I am looking for jquery tree menu which hides nodes which are not parents of selected node

Tags: jquery, menu

I need something like on this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251056.aspx
The menu on the left is what I want - when user selects item then it shows this item children but also hides all parent nodes which are not directly parent of selected node. This is useful for big tree menus.

Comment: Have you found any trees that get close to this?  I.e. is there a tree you're working with that you can customize?  Or are you just looking for the final solution?

Comment: Well I was trying to use jquery treeview plugin but I don't how to make it work as I want...

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Parent</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Children</span></li>
            <li><span>Children</span></li>
            <li><span>Children</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Parent</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Children</span></li>
            <li><span>Children</span></li>
            <li><span>Children</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Parent</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Children</span></li>
            <li><span>Children</span></li>
            <li><span>Children</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Children</span></li>
            <li><span>Children</span></li>
            <li><span>Children</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


<script>
   $('li').on('click',function(){
      $(this)
        .children()  //Selecting children for the clicked li
             .slideDown(200) //Then we show them
                .parent() //slideDown returns children again, so we'll get the parent li again
                  .siblings('li') //and then we'll call his siblings
                      .children()
                           .slideUp(200); //and finally we'll hide their children
   });
</script>
```

Obviously this will need some css, and more javascript, but with that you could get some ideas. (I wrote this here in SO and I haven't tested it, so it may have some bugs)